# How to show vertical scroll bar in mobile browser always

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show vertical scroll bar for mobile browser for always, not only if page hight is increased, i have tried this `html {overflow-y: scroll;}` it works fine in desktop but not in mobile device, any suggestions...!!!

Comment: There are dozens of mobile browsers and hundreds of mobile devices.  Provide more information, code and target devices/browsers if you want any help.  Why not just set a `min-height` on the `body` that forces the body height to always be taller than the viewport?

Comment: Many mobile browsers don't show scrollbars at all, while others show them only while scrolling, regardless of what you put in your CSS. What you want to achieve might not actually be possible.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was possible, this is most likely determined by the browser/device not your code.

Comment: i'm trying to make this for safari web browser and chrome web browser.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since the scroll bars on mobile devices are controlled by the width and height of the body element respectively by the viewport which is very different between devices. Maybe if you target just one device and from what I understand it would be an Iphone ... you can do it using the webkit prefix in css to force a scrollbar.

something like: 

overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Answer (score 0):

If you make something width a fixed height or width container such as a div, and then put another div inside it that is allowed to overflow it with height or width auto and overflow hidden, you can get drag behavior automatically if you set overflow: auto, or even overflow-x: auto or overflow-y: auto on the fixed height / width element.

However, users will not always be able to tell that the area is draggable by visual cues like scrollbars appearing like they do in desktop browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom scroller such as https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll and style a bar of your choice. Mobile example here: https://thoughtand.co/tings/ (This has a chunky looking bar but it can be really whatever you want)